# How to wait for resources to be loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, angularjs

I'm writing an AngularJS application and I'm trying to achieve certain things, but since I'm very new to Angular, I want to have the opinion of some AngularJS experts.

I'm creating a control suite in fact in AngularJS and that consists out of 2 parts, a loading screen and a showing screen, both defined in HTML.

The data which I need to manipulate is stored in JSon files.
To give you an idea, here's the first JSon file:

```
{
  "Styles": [
    { "name": "Blue", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Styles/Blue/OfficeUI.Style.Blue.min.css" },
    { "name": "Green", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Styles/Green/OfficeUI.Style.Green.min.css" },
    { "name": "LightBlue", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Styles/LightBlue/OfficeUI.Style.LightBlue.min.css" },
    { "name": "Orange", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Styles/Orange/OfficeUI.Style.Orange.min.css" },
    { "name": "Purple", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Styles/Purple/OfficeUI.Style.Purple.min.css" },
    { "name": "Red", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Styles/Red/OfficeUI.Style.Red.min.css" },
    { "name": "Turquoise", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Styles/Turquoise/OfficeUI.Style.Turquoise.min.css" }
  ],
  "DefaultStyle": "LightBlue",

  "Themes": [
    { "name": "No Background", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/No Background/OfficeUI.Themes.No-Background.min.css" },
    { "name": "Calligraphy", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Calligraphy/OfficeUI.Themes.Calligraphy.min.css" },
    { "name": "Circles And Stripes", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Circles-And-Stripes/OfficeUI.Themes.Circles-And-Stripes.min.css" },
    { "name": "Circuit", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Circuit/OfficeUI.Themes.Circuit.min.css" },
    { "name": "Clouds", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Clouds/OfficeUI.Themes.Clouds.min.css" },
    { "name": "Doodle Circles", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Doodle-Circles/OfficeUI.Themes.Doodle-Circles.min.css" },
    { "name": "Doodle Diamonds", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Doodle-Diamonds/OfficeUI.Themes.Doodle-Diamonds.min.css" },
    { "name": "Geometry", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Geometry/OfficeUI.Themes.Geometry.min.css" },
    { "name": "Lunchbox", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Lunchbox/OfficeUI.Themes.Lunchbox.min.css" },
    { "name": "School Supplies", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/School-Supplies/OfficeUI.Themes.School-Supplies.min.css" },
    { "name": "Spring", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Spring/OfficeUI.Themes.Spring.min.css" },
    { "name": "Stars", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Stars/OfficeUI.Themes.Stars.min.css" },
    { "name": "Straws", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Straws/OfficeUI.Themes.Straws.min.css" },
    { "name": "Tree Rings", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Tree-Rings/OfficeUI.Themes.Tree-Rings.min.css" },
    { "name": "Underwater", "stylesheet": "/Resources/Stylesheets/Themes/Underwater/OfficeUI.Themes.Underwater.min.css" }
  ],
  "DefaultTheme": "Geometry",
  "Configuration": "/Resources/Data/Application.json",
  "Controls": [
    { "Name": "Ribbon", "ConfigurationFile": "/Configuration/Application/OfficeUI.Ribbon.config.json" }
  ]
}
```

As you see, the file does contain some references to stylesheets which needs to be embedded in the page dynamiccaly.

Now, let's move to the AngularJS part.

First of all, I have the definition of my module:

```
var OfficeUI = angular.module('OfficeUIApplication', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Then, I do have a service which loads the JSon file defined above:

```
OfficeUI.factory('OfficeUIConfigurationService', function($http) {
    // Defines the object that this service needs to return.
    return {
        getOfficeUIConfiguration: function() {
            // Check if the location of the file can be found somewhere. If it cannot be found, throw an error.
            if (typeof $.fn.OfficeUI.Settings.OfficeUIConfigurationFileLocation === 'undefined' || $.fn.OfficeUI.Settings.OfficeUIConfigurationFileLocation == '') {
                OfficeUICore.Exceptions.officeUIConfigurationException('The OfficeUI Configuration file is not defined.');
            }

            // Returns the 'httpPromise' which is required for further processing.
            return $http.get($.fn.OfficeUI.Settings.OfficeUIConfigurationFileLocation)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return {
                        Styles: response.data.Styles,
                        DefaultStyle: response.data.DefaultStyle,
                        Themes: response.data.Themes,
                        DefaultTheme: response.data.DefaultTheme,
                        Configuration: response.data.Configuration,
                        Controls: response.data.Controls
                    };
                }, function(error) { OfficeUICore.Exceptions.officeUILoadingException('The OfficeUI Configuration file: \'' + $.fn.OfficeUI.Settings.OfficeUIConfigurationFileLocation + '\' could not be loaded.'); }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Then, I'm having my controller:

```
OfficeUI.controller('OfficeUIController', function(OfficeUIConfigurationService, $scope, $http) {
    $scope.isInitialized = false;           // Indicates that the entire OfficeUI application has been loaded.
    $scope.loadingScreenLoaded = false;     // Indicates that the data for the loading screen has been loaded.

    // Initialize all the required components for the website.
    Initialize();

    function Initialize() {
        OfficeUIConfigurationService.getOfficeUIConfiguration().then(function(data) {
            var foundStyles = JSPath.apply('.{.name == "' + data.DefaultStyle + '"}', data.Styles);
            var foundThemes = JSPath.apply('.{.name == "' + data.DefaultTheme + '"}', data.Themes);

            $scope.Style = foundStyles[0].stylesheet;
            $scope.Theme = foundThemes[0].stylesheet;

            // Set a value that indicates that the loading screen has been loaded. So, at this point, the loading screen
            // can be rendered.
            $scope.loadingScreenLoaded = true;

            // Returns the 'httpPromise' which is required for further processing.
            $http.get(data.Configuration)
                .then(function (response) {
                        $scope.Title = response.data.Title;
                        $scope.Icons = response.data.Icons;
                }, function(error) { OfficeUICore.Exceptions.officeUILoadingException('The OfficeUI application definition file: \'' + data.Configuration + '\' could not be loaded.'); }
            );
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.isInitialized = true;
            $scope.$apply();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

**Note:** I do set a timeout here, to make sure that the loading screen is being displayed for 2 seconds.

In this controller, you find the following piece of code:

```
OfficeUIConfigurationService.getOfficeUIConfiguration().then(function(data) {
    var foundStyles = JSPath.apply('.{.name == "' + data.DefaultStyle + '"}', data.Styles);
    var foundThemes = JSPath.apply('.{.name == "' + data.DefaultTheme + '"}', data.Themes);
    $scope.Style = foundStyles[0].stylesheet;
    $scope.Theme = foundThemes[0].stylesheet;
    // Set a value that indicates that the loading screen has been loaded. So, at this point, the loading screen
    // can be rendered.
    $scope.loadingScreenLoaded = true;
    // Returns the 'httpPromise' which is required for further processing.
    $http.get(data.Configuration)
        .then(function (response) {
                $scope.Title = response.data.Title;
                $scope.Icons = response.data.Icons;
        }, function(error) { OfficeUICore.Exceptions.officeUILoadingException('The OfficeUI application definition file: \'' + data.Configuration + '\' could not be loaded.'); }
    );
});
```

What this does is, from my loading service, retrieve and parse the JSon file, and based on the values in this file, assign a value to `Style` and `Theme`, which both are scopes objects.

In my HTML, this is being rendered like this (in the head section of the file):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#" data-ng-href="{{Style}}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#" data-ng-href="{{Theme}}" />
```

This allows me to change the look and feel of my application dynamiccaly (by calling a method which change the scope value).

However, there can be a flickering issue. When the Json file is loaded and parsed, I assign a value to `loadingScreenLoaded` which makes sure that the loading screen is being showed:

```
<div class="loading-area center-screen no-select" data-ng-if="loadingScreenLoaded && !isInitialized">
```

However, at this particular case, it might be that the CSS file is still loading.

So the question is, how to not show the loading div on the page, until all the resources have been loaded (CSS, ...)

Also, if possible, is there a way to do the same with ng-include directive, images, ...

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not recommended to use timeout, I cannot expect that your resources will be ready after 2000

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.isInitialized = true;
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 2000);
```

I will recommend you to use file and module loader library. Try to use angular with [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

See this example of using [angularjs + requirejs](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/)

Comment: There's a note on the question saying that right now, it's only implemented to make sure that the loading screen is displayed for 2 seconds (otherwise it will disappear almost immediately). And I don't see how requireJS could help me in this situation. The question is how to wait until resources are ready, A.K.A. Preloading.

Answer (score 0):

Tag  has event "onload". Details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link). But you should check browser compatibility if it satisfies all browser that you need.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css" onload="sheetLoaded()" onerror="sheetError()">
```

In other case you can consider dynamic resource loading techniques. For example [this](http://deano.me/2012/09/jquery-load-css-with-ajax-all-browsers/). Also, you can use  third-party libraries which actually implements dynamic resource loading([angular-load](https://github.com/urish/angular-load) or, as @ran said, requirejs).

> The question is how to wait until resources are ready

You can attach event handler to "onload"(or third-party library specific event, it depends what you choose) which will be executed when your resources are ready.